# Using Reflector, why can't I see the app.manifest embedded in my .NET app?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, windows-vista, uac, reflector

I have a WinForms .NET app that, according to the Vista Task Manager with UAC enabled, runs with virtualization "Disabled" even though I do not recall adding a manifest with "asInvoker" to the app. VS.NET (this project has gone through all four versions of VS.NET) must have added the **\Properties\app.manifest** file I see in Solution Explorer, but this file does not contain the **trustinfo** element I would have expected to disable virtualization. So I fired up Reflector to see what might be embedded into my actual executable, but I cannot find the app.manifest file. Should I be able to find the manifest or signs of it in the executable? According to VS 2008, the build action is **BaseApplicationManifest**, but does this mean it is not embedded in the exectable? Can someone explain why my app runs with Virtualization disabled if I did not ask it to and, once explained, can someone point me to where I find the artifact that causes this in my app via Reflector?

As a followup to the app.manifest being in my solution for who knows how long, it is filled up with all kinds of IPermissions that I'm not sure I need any more. What adds content to this file and can it contain permissions I no longer need? Should it be pruned or managed? Should I explicitly add trustinfo to it? I guess app.manifest is just a mystery that I need to learn more about.

**Update:** From [this article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2007.06.uac.aspx), I learned I can use the SysInternals/Microsoft Sigcheck utility to see the following info, but I have no idea how my app got signed with MyApplication.app. Where is this happening in the build process?

```
c:\Users\Public\Programs\SysinternalsSuite>sigcheck.exe -m ceo.exe

sigcheck v1.54 - sigcheck
Copyright (C) 2004-2008 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

"c:\Users\Public\Programs\SysinternalsSuite\ceo.exe":
        Verified:       Unsigned
        File date:      1:47 PM 2/6/2009
        Publisher:      CEO Image Systems
        Description:    Main Menu
        Product:        Image Executive CEO
        Version:        2.0.0.0
        File version:   2.0.0.0
        Manifest:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
  <assemblyIdentity version="1.0.0.0" name="MyApplication.app"/>
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
        <requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false"/>
      </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
  </trustInfo>
</assembly>
```

**Update 2:** Looks like I will get there eventually. VS 2008 added a **Manifest** option on the executable's project page for which my project has "Embed manifest with default settings" selected. So this answers how it got there, but how can I see this in Reflector?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe it is a win32 resource and therefore can't be seen by Reflector? You could see win32 resources with a win32 resource editor like [this one](http://www.wilsonc.demon.co.uk/d10resourceeditor.htm).

Comment: Yup, it is an unmanaged resource, which VS.NET can display just by opening up the executable (thanks to nobugz on that one).

Answer (score 9):

Reflector doesn't let you see unmanaged resources.  You don't need a special tool, just use Visual Studio's File + Open + File and select your .exe to browse the resources.  The manifest is accessible through the RT_MANIFEST node.  The viewer is not very friendly, you'll get a hex dump.  You can use the context menu to export it to a text file.

The C# and VB.NET compilers automatically generate a Vista compatible manifest.  You can override this with the [/win32manifest command line option](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb545961.aspx?ppud=4).  Which is what the IDE will do automatically when you use Project + Add New Item + Application Manifest File.

Comment: You definitely get +1 for saying I can use VS.NET to see unmanaged resources.